# Visual Studio crashes when I view a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, crash

I start up an existing solution, click on a JavaScript file, the file opens up in the IDE for a few seconds and then visual studio disappears.  This is consistent and reproducible.

I saw this patch for KB958502 and installed it but it didn't seem to do anything.

Any suggestions on how i can proceed as this is completely stopping my development here.

Also, any questions that would help make this question easier to answer (log files, etc) as i couldn't really think of any other descriptions or artifacts to help explain the situation.

Comment: Tried just re-installing VS? Could be problems with intellisense or just about anything else for that matter :P

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As a temporary solution you could edit this specific file in Notepad++ instead of VS.

Comment: @Cornflake - that is what i am doing now.  not ideal but gets the job done

Answer (score 4):

I know this was asked over a year ago but I suspect the culprit is a plugin / extension.
If anybody else has this same issue try starting visual studio in SafeMode:

```
Devenv.exe /SafeMode
```

This prevents all third-party plug-ins from loading.

This helped me identify why my VS was crashing with JS files.

Answer (score 0):

Another switch I  suggest using  is:

```
Devenv /log Path\NameOfLogFile
```